# Unknown build Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, import

So i am trying to import the [metro](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) chart into my visual studio 2010 project (WPF)

At home (in Visual studio 2012) it worked perfectly. I know that sometimes you cannot copy 2012 projects into 2010 and i therefore saved the source code into txt files and copy pasted it into my new project.

But i get the following error:

> Unknown build error, 'Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

My theory is that it might be because visual studio 2012 cannot handle the lib. (the metro lib which is made in 2012) but i was wondering if any of you have encountered the same problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory.

`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute` is .NET 4.5 only.

Your visual studio 2010 will be running .NET 4.0 which doesn't support this type.

Comment: is there an update for visual studio 2010 to run 4.5 or do you need visual studio 2012?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't run 4.5 on VS2010 unfortunately. I would recommend installing VS2012 on the second machine.

Comment: and if that machine runs on Windows XP?

Comment: Then you're screwed: [http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web#product-express-web-requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web#product-express-web-requirements)